Sliding glass door doesn't seal and debris gets inside
I have a three-panel stacking sliding glass door that seems to have an issue with the weatherproofing. The panel that locks to the wall will get debris blown in from the outside while the rest of the door panels seem to block things just fine.
The doors have screws on either side behind black rubber that can adjust the track up or down, but also the inside weatherstripping seems like it might be missing a small section toward the bottom. Any suggestions on what can be done to prevent stuff from blowing in?





Looks like you need to clean debris out of the track. Then there won't be so much to blow in.

Yeah, no seal works well when it's neglected for years. Get scrubbing, then see how it does. That tiny gap in the last photo can't be letting much past. If it is, replace it.

Observation's: You have totally rotten wood on the outside frame. Fix that. Next : Clean the groove next to the sliding door rail On the inside and insert rubber seal.

Once you clean out the tracks you need to check if the weather-stripping at the  bottom is in good condition or that your door is squared properly to have good contact with the weather-stripping where it meets the door jamb. Your first picture shows that the bottom of the door is sliding in grooves with weather-stripping on both sides each groove. If you are getting debris in the house, this means the seal at the bottom is not working.
